# Script Shell: How to use a script that I created when I'm not in the directory he is

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I created a `mv_file.sh` script and I want to use it even if I'm not in the path where the script is located.

My question is: What do I have to do to use `./mv_file` instead of `mv`, and this whatever the path I'm in.

Comment: add it to PATH variable

Comment: You mean in the binary PATH ?

Comment: go to the directory where your script is. then open terminal and enter this:       export PATH=$(pwd):$PATH

Comment: Or just literally call it with a full path. `/path/to/my/script` is a perfectly valid way to execute something. Saying `./thing` just means "look for `thing` in `.`, which is a synonym for "the current directory". That's why adding it to the path will still fail if you type `./thing` unless you happen to be in the directory with it. Am I off base here? Or would it be helpful to have a full-blown answer elaborating on this?

Comment: @PaulHodges I could swear I remember a previous question that covered this, but I can't find it. If nobody else can either, I'd support having a full answer to this.

Comment: I second what @PaulHodges said.. We don't know the full context but calling a script with './scriptname' should generally not be a requirement for execution outside of its directory when you can refer to its full path and avoid future confusion for someone else parsing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the directory, where your script is, to your path. Open `~/.bash_profile` (or whatever you choose to use, this sometimes in `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh for example) And add:

```
PATH=/path/to/script:$PATH
```

OR you can add the script to a directory that's already in your path. For gnu/linux for example that might be:

```
$HOME/bin
```

To see what you're current PATH is:

```
echo $PATH
```

If memory serves, this should work just as well on a mac.